# hashing two inputs with a single encryption

Tags: encryption, hash

I'm looking at hash function constructions that use ciphers. There are many which are analyzed in this paper: [https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/hash.pdf](https://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/%7Erogaway/papers/hash.pdf) but all of them assume that only a single input of the message is "absorbed" when using an encryption algorithm.

What if you have an input of length 2 (`[x, y]`) and want to use a single encryption? Are there schemes that use an initial state as `x` and use `m_i = y`?

Comment: What about SHA2 that uses the so-called [SHACAL2 block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHACAL)? - well specially designed for hashing. AES cannot be used since it has related key attacks and besides the blocksize is too small for MD constructions

Comment: SHA2 uses Merkle-Damgard which in each iteration uses the previous state and a block of message, I want to use two block of messages in the same iteration specifically :o

Comment: I rather get hard time understanding the question, so what are the actual sizes of your blocks?

Comment: In theory, at least, we can simply define a large enough blocker such that some encoding of the pairs fit into the domain of the block cipher. The encoding can just be concatenation, assuming pairs of bit strings

Comment: I guess I'm asking more of a theoretical question, if I have two blocks of the size of the key or input of the cipher, is there a construction that allows me to hash them using a single instance of the cipher? For example `E(k=m1, m2) + m1 + m2`

Comment: @David天宇Wong, I think the confusion is that it's not clear if your overall hash construction takes as input a pair or a sequence of pairs. In the latter case where we think of $h = H(a,b)$ and $a,b$ is of fixed size, any of the design in PGV or the reference you link will work. For instance, Davies-Meier $E(x,y) \oplus y$ is known to be collision resistant in the ideal-cipher model. But for sequences of tuples like in iterative hashing, then you need to absorb some chaining value as well somehow.

Comment: Would [TupleHash](https://handwiki.org/wiki/SHA-3#Additional_instances) work for you?